# CVE-2022-22965 Vulnerable VMware Spring Beans 5.2.0 reported even after updating pom with version 5.2.22

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-bean, cve-2022-22965

I am using Java 11 and currently in pom.xml I am using spring framework version as 5.2.22

In my pom these dependencies are also there

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-security-parent</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Still the security vulnerability is reported that :-

```
CVE-2022-22965 Vulnerable software installed: VMware Spring Beans 5.2.0
```

Not sure which old spring dependency is causing this vulnerability. I even tried creating maven dependency tree but could not figure out due to which dependency this issue is reported.
Please suggest how can I mitigate this vulnerability

Comment: Your issues are created then that. You are mixing different versions of a framework (Spring, Spring Security) that is trouble waiting to happen. Next to that that scan is borked as it doesn't look at the actual pom but rather the individual dependencies. So if one of those is using that version you will get the warning.

Comment: how can I make sure the correct combination of Spring & Spring Security. could you please suggest.

Comment: As I stated the problem is mixing versions of a framework, for Spring Security you are mixing 5.7.2, 5.1.6, 5.0.0 and for Spring, at least, something in the 5.x range (depending on the Spring Security versions) and 4.3.2 and then whatever `okta-spring-security-parent` is pulling in (something old probably as that is for Spring Boot 1.5.4).

Comment: I tried using Spring security 5.7.2 with Spring framework 5.2.22 version but somehow my application was throwing some errors.. I am trying to figure out the compatibility of spring framework version 5.2.22 with some stable version of spring security..

Comment: no luck so far , I have checked my maven dependencies and no jar is using 5.2.0 I have used BOM for spring framework as well as for spring security but still I am getting this vulnerability

Comment: As I stated before, the check is borked. It doesn't check your final pom it checks the dependencies. If one of that has declared that version of a dependency it will generate a warning even if you aren't actually using that version of Spring Beans. The check is wrong.

Comment: I understand your point.. but how can I mitigate this warning, as it is a legacy code so I dont think I have that liberty to do multiple changes.. is there a way to do clean upgrade of spring framework as well as spring security

Comment: Sigh... I give up... Read... The check is wrong not your dependencies.

Comment: So sorry to bother you M. Deinum. Do you mean I should check with the vulnerability scan team as why they are reporting this as my dependencies seems OK ?