# What is the compatible version of Spring-security with spring framework 5.2.22.RELEASE?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jar, spring-bean

Which version of spring security is compatible with Spring framework 5.2.22.RELEASE?

My jars are:-

```
spring-web-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar
spring-jcl-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-5.2.22.RELEASE.jar
```

Security jars are:-

```
spring-security-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-acl-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-oauth2-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-oauth2-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72849144/cve-2022-22965-vulnerable-vmware-spring-beans-5-2-0-reported-even-after-updating). First fix your dependencies so you stop mixing Spring and Spring Security modules from different versions. I Strongly suggest to use the BOM to include the proper dependency versions (saves you from manually defining them each time).

Comment: Could you please give me some reference, i tried using this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/get-spring-security.html  but my pom gave some errors after this

Comment: I have used bom  as follows:-
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.22.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Comment: no luck so far , I have checked my maven dependencies and no jar is using 5.2.0 I have used BOM for spring framework as well as for spring security but still I am getting this vulnerability